# Bulk change the order date for all orders of a specific product in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How would I bulk change the order date for a specific product in Woocommerce?

We have an integration into Royal Mail click and dropto create postage, but the royal mail integration only downloads orders made in the past 7 days. When pre-orders get released that were made over a week ago they don't get transferred over unless I change the order date, and its a slow process to do manually.

I would love to be able to simplify this.
Happy to run a custom piece of SQL.
Any ideas?

Comment: "When pre-orders get released that were made over a week ago" how you release those orders ?

Comment: It’s done automatically by the pre-order plug-in, or you can manually change them using the plug-in ui.

Comment: But the change needs to happen once they have converted into standard orders

Comment: Ask plugin author about the event that manage this change. Use it to get the order id and modify date after ? There are many plugins and cant tell which one you have. And if its premium its difficult someone here to help unless they have the plugin. So your best bet is to try contact plugin author or search in code.

Comment: I'm more thinking of some custom SQL I can run to manually do it. The woocommerce pre-order is a huge commercial plugin developed by Woocommerce themselves, and mine is a specific use case.

Comment: Dont worry, I found a plugin that does what I want.